# Does the keyword 'this' return a reference or a value

Tags: c#, oop, this, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Whenever the keyword `this` is called inside a C# class, does it return a reference to the instance that it appears in, or does it return the value of the instance (like a copy)?

For example, would the following code print the number 23 (meaning `this` returned a copy of `foo`), or the number 96 (meaning `this` returned a reference to `foo`)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { 23 };
        foo.Bar();
        Console.Write(foo.FooBar);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int FooBar { get; set; }

    public void Bar()
    {
        Foo newFoo = this;
        newFoo.FooBar = 96;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you run this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `this` relates to a reference type (`class`), it returns a reference to the instance. Using `this` is no different from using `foo2` in the following code snippet:

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = foo1;
```

In the same way as `foo2` only references (!) the object referenced by `foo1`, inside of the class, `this` only references the instance.

If it was different, it would be impossible to e.g. assign a value to a property of an object from inside a method, as using `this` would always result in a copied object, which in turn means you would never set the value of the original instance's field, which would be rather bad.

So, to cut a long story short: `this` holds a reference, not the value.

HTH

Comment: Could I get a copy instead of a reference by using `this.MemberwiseClone()`?

Comment: You would get a "shallow copy". In this contrived example, it would be enough but if original Foo referenced another object rather than simple value types, then your clone of foo whilst itself being a unique object would have a reference to the same child object instances.